# How to implement vertical scroll bar highlights in Visual Studio 2015 extension

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vs-extensibility

I'm doing a research on a Visual Studio 2015 code analysis extension which require a horizontal scroll bar highlights with following features,

**Display a status indicator in horizontal scroll bar.**

[image]

**Mark the horizontal scroll bar**

[image]

I have seen some extensions wit this feature in the VS gallery, Does anyone know how to implement this since there are not much information related to this in MSDN archives?